# Extending my stay in the US by crossing the Canadian border and entering again with ESTA

Tags: visas, usa, esta, j1-visas

I am currently in the US under a J-1 student visa. It's an exchange student program, and after the end of this school year, I'll get released from the program and will be able to stay for additional 30 days (grace period for J-1 visas). I would, however, like to stay a few days after the grace period ends. Would it be possible for me to cross the border with Canada and exit the US with my J-1 visa and reenter it with an ESTA to get a few additional days in the US?

Comment: How will you explain to the US CBP official why you want a few additional days over and above the 30 day grace period? How will you convince them of your intention to leave again?

Comment: It’s been firmly established that entering Canada or Mexico do not count for resetting the amount of time spent in the USA. This is different however I expect it to meet with grief. I would say forget it

Comment: Why not just request adjustment of status to B2?

Comment: @littleadv's suggestion comes with higher fees (but no travel costs).  It also has the significant advantage of avoiding the risk of being denied reentry.  That would be a serious blow to your plans, wouldn't it?

Comment: @phoog Out of interest, if the OP requested adjustment of status but was denied (not sure how likely that is), would the denial need to be disclosed on any subsequent visa application that asked about such things?